# Customize docbook the preferred way

Tags: extend, docbook

I'd like to add a few elements to docbook 5 and to change a few elements. The question is: what is the preferred way?

My root element looks like this:

```
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0">
</book>
```

And I guess I should change it to

```
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0-extension acme-1.0">
</book>
```

Or something like this. Should I change the namespace as well? I believe I should, but this gives me some trouble, as the RelaxNG grammar expects the namespace to be `http://docbook.org/ns/docbook` and not for example `http://example.org/ns/docbook-myextension`.

My `.rng` file looks like this:

```
<grammar xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">
   <include href="docbookxi.rng">
      <!-- change things here -->
   </include>
   <!-- add things here -->
</grammar>
```

Comment: "If you change the DocBook schema, the namespace remains the same, but you must provide an alternate version identifier for the schema and the modules you changed." See http://docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/ch05.html#s-dbversion

Comment: @mzjn Somehow I have read the page a few times but missed that sentence. Thank you for the pointer!